# half-opaque colors of TikZ differ in PS and PDF

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, dvips, postscript, shadows

Consider the file mwe.tex containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=1cm,paperheight=1.5cm,margin=0cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw=black,opacity=.5,fill=gray](A){};
  \node[draw=black,fill=gray!50,below of=A]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Let's run `latex mwe && dvips -o mwe.ps mwe.dvi && dvipdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY mwe.dvi mwe.pdf && ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY mwe.ps mwe.ps.pdf` on Debian. As a result we get mwe.ps, mwe.pdf, and mwe.ps.pdf, shown in the next screenshot in this order in the viewer gv:

[image: output]

As we see, the fill color of the upper box in the visual representation of the PostScript file is more intense than in the visual representations of the PDF files.  The same result is observable in evince and okular.

Such differences shouldn't happen. (No real knowledge of why this happens, but it looks that the transparency probably doesn't make it to PostScript, though, purely technically, in Postscript one could simply reduce the intensity of gray, as shown in the lower box, or create a dotted filling.) Which output is correct, which output is wrong, who is the real culprit, whom to blame, and what to do?

Comment: why do you assume that a ps/dvi viewer can show transparency?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I never claimed that a dvi viewer can show transparency. As for Postscript, opacity= in such easy cases as ours would simply amount to, for example, multiplying the gray color intensity by , or to a dotted shadow, in which only each second gray dot is set.

Comment: sure you do. You are complaining that the view with the postscript doesn't show the transparency. The transparency is in the postscript, as it finds its way into the PDF. If your viewer ignores it is a viewer problem/decision.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Three different viewers (gv, evince, okular) ignoring the transparency in mwe.ps is strange. Of course, under the assumption that the PostScript output is wrong and the PDF output is right (which I don't know myself for sure).

Comment: postscript doesn't natively support transparency, it only pass it through to pdf. The viewers could use the info nevertheless, but if they don't it is not really surprising. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29324411/11796366

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand. If we believe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(graphic)#Transparency_in_PostScript, some support for transparency in Postscript is present. If not, then, as I said, making the color less intense or having a dotted filling is probably the way to go.